# jQuery When(promisesArray).always() firing after ANY

Tags: javascript, jquery

the following code is firing my `setButtons` function after ANY of the promises complete, and not ALL!!! how do I fix that?

```
var promises = [];
var c = 0;
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    promises.push(GetReservation(item.UniqueId,
        apiRoot,
        function (data2) {
            //do stuff including increment c
            console.log('DONE! count=' + c);
        },
        function (x, y, z) {
            if (x.status == 404) {
                //OK, no reserve! this is expected!
            }
        }));
})
$.when.apply($, promises).always(function () {
    setButtons(box, c)
});
```

Comment: Show us the rest of the code, how you're creating the promises array etc

Comment: @adeneo there! the promises are created fine as far as i can tell...

Comment: It's impossible to tell what those functions return, do they actually return valid promises ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c65qb/ Works fine

Comment: Are any of your ajax calls failing? When will immediately reject the whole 'bundled' promise if one of the promises is rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is promises an actual array of promises/deferreds? Always will immediately resolve if the when is passed anything besides an array of deferreds/promises.

EDIT

Yep, that's what is likely happening. You probably aren't returning anything from that function, so promises is (probably) an array of 'undefined' values, which will immediately resolve when passed to `$.when`

Please check the return value of `GetReserva` to ensure it returns promises.

EDIT

`$.when` will reject the resulting promise immediately if one of the constituent promises is rejected. Maybe one failing `ajax` call is  occurring, short circuiting the whole thing.

Comment: actually no... promisses are real/initialized objects... and When is waiting, but not until all promisses are done... whenever any gets completed, its firing!

Comment: How do you know what `GetReservation()` returns, it's not posted, the functions posted are the callbacks, the `GetReservation()` function could return anything ?

Comment: Yep, making a likely guess. The syntax around the $.when call is correct, so the culprit is -likely- the return value of that method, being pushed onto the promises array.

Comment: Also, if one of the ajax requests fails, always is called immediately on failure ?

Comment: I do expect some of the calls to fail (i do expect some 404 - meaning that item is not reserved!) im handling the errors...

Comment: Right, but When will immediately reject itself if one of the constituent promises is rejected. That could be it.

Comment: If some fail, `$.when` calls `always` right away, it doesn't wait for the rest to complete, doesn't matter if you're handling errors or not.

Comment: Trust me, if any of them fail, always is called before the rest completes.

Comment: @adeneo correct! i changed the server side to return null and it worked as expected... pls post that as answer and claim your prize!